# Exec SQL Server stored procedure in a server from php codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures

Trying to execute a SQL Server stored procedure on a server using codeigniter but it seems that the query doesn't get any output and no error prompts either, for now I've removed the parameters thinking that it will smooth things up but it didn't.

Is it possible to access this stored procedure and if it is, can I also run it with parameters like two date parameters?

PS: All the connections are good I've tried to retrieve records from another table from this SQL Server and I got it..

[image: SQL Server stored procedure]

[image: My code]

Comment: this is resolved..

i think the problem was the name of the temp table which is "#CST"..

What i did is breakdown all the queries in my model and query it 1 by 1..